# Yeoman generator after download call function

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to create a Yeoman generator.
I need to know how is possibile to call a function after bowerInstall finished to download my package.

Here is my piece of code:

```
Generator.prototype.myFiles = function myFiles() {
    console.info('download');
    this.bowerInstall('my-package-name', { save: true });
};

Generator.prototype.moveFiles = function moveFiles() {
    console.info('move');
};
```

After download I need to move some files so I have to wait until all package is downloaded.

But function moveFiles is called immediately when the download start not when the download is finished.

Is there anyway to call moveFiles after download my package?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should read the documentation to understand how Yeoman generators works. For this question, you're asking about the task queue and the priorities: http://yeoman.io/authoring/running-context.html

Installation actions happens in the `install`. So to do anything after the installation complete, you need to add your tasks inside the `end` priority.

In your case, it'd look like:

```
Generator.prototype.install = function myFiles() {
    console.info('download');
    this.bowerInstall('my-package-name', { save: true });
};

Generator.prototype.end = function moveFiles() {
    console.info('move');
};
```

Comment: can you please make a simple example with my code? Because I have read documentation but there isn't an example like mine

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help